# How do I start programming graphical Windows programs?

Tags: c, wpf, windows, winapi, user-interface

After a few minutes of searching I've learned that the Win32 API is the lowest-level way to write graphical Windows programs. Is this true? Is there a way to draw things directly to the video buffer? How do demo-coders write demos?

Anyway, I know a bit of C, which seems to be the preferred way to write Win32 programs, and I'm interested in sticking to the lowest-level and most flexible way to write Windows programs.

I've heard of many different frameworks just from Microsoft themselves, .NET, Windows Forms, WPF, MFC, WTL, CLR, ATL. (Can someone clarify which of these actually depends on another?)

Then of course there are the cross-platform toolkits, WxWidgets, GTK, Qt, Mono, tk etc.

What if I just want to write an entire interface in OpenGL?
Does everything really depend on the Win32 API?
Will I have to write some code that uses Win32 API calls to at least create a window for OpenGL to use?

Comment: @TomTom, yet this can, by accident, become useful for other members.

Comment: EVERYTHING can become usefull for someone else. This is hardly a relevant criteria.

Comment: I wrote this question in a two minute stream-of-consciousness (clearly), and I know that WPF is a component of .NET among other things. I'm actually cracking up reading what I wrote. The fact of the matter is, I've always wanted to know how to write "real" Windows programs, and I figured this got that message across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically asked so much questions in one question that I don't know for sure what you want. However, I will try my best to make reasonable assumptions and answer all your questions briefly.

Win32 API is not just the lowest level API to graphical programs but to any window program. It's closest to kernel, however it's not necessary to write in it.

I assume here that you want to make a graphic fancy App.

Win32 API has a component, called GDI, Graphic Device Interface, which you can use to interact with graphical buffers, however it's painfully slow. So then you can use OpenGL or DirectX. Also MFC was before .NET, you used it to created standard windows GUI programs. Then came .NET, more slow but a bit better designed.

And yes there are many Cross Platform options, like you mentioned, you can use them too, but all depends on what you are trying to do.

Now if you want to write a pure graphical app, like games or fancy demos with shiny graphics, you should really not care about Win32, MFC, .NET etc, because when you want to create such an app you only use bare minimum of Win32 to create a skeleton window, and then your OpenGL or DirectX takes over control. 
But of course, if it's a window app, it will surely use Win32 API somewhere down there, not that you have to care about it though :)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted to know. One thing, when I see a program from the demoscene that seems to not be resizeable but it can still be moved around (like a Win32 chip-disk), is that program using a "Window" at all? If so, is the title-bar hidden or skinned over?

Comment: Glad you like my answer, you can mark it the correct answer if you think its best.

Now, When you create your skeleton application, you can set certain properties of it. Like weather it will have an option to be maximized, resized and so on. I strongly suggest reading basic tutorials of developing OpenGL apps on windows, if you are after that.

Comment: @James: Windows don't necessarily have to have chrome/decoration.  Think for example of how a splash screen (image with no controls) is displayed.  If you read up on the Win32 API, poke around with things like Spy++, learn about UI automation, etc, this will all become more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library called GLUT if your entire application is going to be OpenGL.

http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Win32 is the lowest-level API. It wraps all the OS objects and API, as well as exposes the windowing API, so you can create your OpenGL window, etc. Everything else is built on top of it.

You cannot draw directly to video memory like a demo coder on an Amiga 500; you haven't been able to safely get a pointer to the video output buffer since the mid 90s using DOS. :)

If you want to learn Windows at the lowest level, in C, get a copy of [Programming Windows](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/) by Charles Petzold. It has absolutely everything you need.

If all you want is to open a window to put GL code into, you should be easily able to find tutorials for that.

Answer (score 0):

You certanly need to do some boilerplate stuff to create Windows application (register window class etc). After you created your app class, you are free to do whatever you want. You can't however have direct access to video memory (which is good thing), but there is DirectX and OpenGL for you.